# ActionScript 3 Selecting Files according to their extensions

Tags: actionscript-3, air, filter, adobe

I'm trying to select for example XML files in a folder. Following code is a part of my program.

```
var desktop:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("puzzles");
var files:Array = desktop.getDirectoryListing();
```

Here I get the path of puzzles in puzzles folder and put them in an array

```
for (var i:uint = 0; i < files.length; i++)
{
    var newtext:Array = files[i].name.split(".")
    PuzzlesNameArray[i] = newtext[0];
}
```

This is only a part of codes. My problem is that here I get path of folder with `newtext[0];` however, I want to select XML files in this `newtext[0]` folder. How can I create such extension filtering or is there any other way to solve this problem.

Comment: Did you read the manual? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html#extension

Comment: I didn't read sorry. Now I'll try to use get extension. You helped me a lot today thanks :)

Comment: upvote for calling it a manual.